# How to use controllerAs syntax with AngularJS modal in case of "modal in the same controller" approach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controlleras

This is my modal function:

```
vm.openUpdateStateModal = function (nextState, idea) {
  $scope.nextState = nextState;
  $scope.idea = idea;
  $scope.modalWindowOpen = true;

  $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'updateStateModal',
    windowClass: 'updateStateModal',
    scope: $scope
  });

  $scope.modalInstance.result.then(function () {
    $scope.updateState(nextState, idea);
  });

  $scope.modalInstance.result.finally(function () {
    $scope.modalWindowOpen = false;
  });
};
```

I don't want to have another controller for my modal, that's why i just give my $scope as parameter, instead of mapping the parameters separately. So on the view side, i can use all the $scope variables.

Yesterday i updated my controller to the controllerAs syntax like this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('IdeaCtrl', function ($scope, ...) {

    var vm = this;
    ...
```

Now how can i adapt this modal function to this new syntax? The challenge for me is: I reuse the view of modal window more than once, also on my main view (without modal). And this view is already adapted to the new syntax "vm.data" instead of "data".

I tried to give my vm as scope, it did not work. How can i handle this?

**EDIT:**

I have changed my function to this:

```
vm.openUpdateStateModal = function (nextState, idea) {
  $scope.nextState = nextState;
  $scope.idea = idea;
  $scope.modalWindowOpen = true;

  $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'updateStateModal',
    windowClass: 'updateStateModal',
    controller: 'IdeaCtrl as vm',
    scope: $scope
  });

  $scope.modalInstance.result.then(function () {
    $scope.updateState(nextState, idea);
  });

  $scope.modalInstance.result.finally(function () {
    $scope.modalWindowOpen = false;
  });
};
```

So i added this line:

```
controller: 'IdeaCtrl as vm',
```

Now it seems ok. But i still i have to use the idea and nextstate variables from the scope. How can i use also those from vm?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164281/pass-current-scope-to-modalinstance-when-using-controlleras-syntax

Comment: it is not exactly the same i think since i don't want to use a separate ctrl for modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have made it like this:

```
vm.openUpdateStateModal = function (nextState, idea) {
  vm.modalWindowOpen = true;
  vm.nextState = nextState;
  $scope.idea = idea;

  vm.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'updateStateModal',
    windowClass: 'updateStateModal',
    scope: $scope
  });

  vm.modalInstance.result.then(function () {
    vm.updateState(nextState, idea);
  });

  vm.modalInstance.result.finally(function () {
    vm.modalWindowOpen = false;
  });
};
```

On the view side, i use the idea from scope, and the other variables from vm. I have to use idea directly from scope, since i have sth like this on my main view:

```
ng-repeat="idea in vm.awesomeIdeas
```

..and i cannot define sth like this:

```
ng-repeat="vm.idea in vm.awesomeIdeas
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use adopted modal views to use `vm` as a prefix for controller reference, then the scope you are passing to modal template should have `vm` property. Then all you have to do is to make sure you set this `vm` property:

```
$scope.vm = this;

$scope.openUpdateStateModal = function(nextState, idea) {
    $scope.nextState = nextState;
    $scope.idea = idea;
    $scope.modalWindowOpen = true;

    $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'updateStateModal',
        windowClass: 'updateStateModal',
        scope: $scope
    });

    $scope.modalInstance.result.then(function() {
        $scope.updateState(nextState, idea);
    });

    $scope.modalInstance.result.finally(function() {
        $scope.modalWindowOpen = false;
    });
};
```

So if you know that you are going to open a modal which uses `vm` as controllerAs prefix then just provide this `vm` as `$scope.vm = this;` in this scope.

Comment: it does not work.. it also sounds a bit strange for me, i already assign "this" to "var vm".. then i create another vm in scope and assign "this" again.