# Access parent controller in $uibmodal without using scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have trouble in accessing the parent controller methods/variables inside $uibmodal

My HTML modal:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl as vm">
  <div class="modal-demo lg">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

      qweqweqweqweqw

      {{vm.test}}fwewewerwqqwer
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="vm.ok()">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="vm.ok()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
AltoDevApp.controller('TestCtrl', ['$uibModal',
    function TestCtrl($uibModal) {
    $uibModal.open({
              ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
              ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
              templateUrl: 'member/professional/profile/education/partials/upload.html',
              controller: angular.noop,
              controllerAs: 'vm'
            });

 vm.ok = function () {
    alert('hi');
  };
    }]);
})();
```

But it is not possible to access the vm.ok() from the model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass current scope to modalInstance when using controllerAs syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164281/pass-current-scope-to-modalinstance-when-using-controlleras-syntax)

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you don't want to pass $scope in $uibModal??

Answer (score 1):

Use a different name for the `controllerAs` property in the modal definition object:

```
AltoDevApp.controller('TestCtrl', ['$uibModal',
  function TestCtrl($uibModal) {

    $uibModal.open({
          ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
          ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
          templateUrl: 'member/professional/profile/education/partials/upload.html',
          controller: angular.noop,
          //controllerAs: 'vm'
          //USE different name
          controllerAs: 'modalvm'
     });

     var vm = this;    
     vm.ok = function () {
        alert('hi');
     };
}]);
```

When a child controller is bound to the same property name as the parent, the child property name (`vm`) hides the parent property name (`vm`). If the child is bound with a different name, the parent property can be accessed by prototypical inheritance.

For more infomation, see [AngularJS Wiki - What are the nuances of scope prototypal inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

---

> Nested scopes is where we see great return from the Controller as syntax, often we’ve had to use the current scope’s `$parent` property to scale back up scopes to get where we need.
>
> Things are far clearer and variables can be accessed properly across scopes:
>
> ```
> <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
>   {{ main.title }}
>   <div ng-controller="AnotherCtrl as another">
>     Scope title: {{ another.title }}
>     Parent title: {{ main.title }}
>     <div ng-controller="YetAnotherCtrl as yet">
>       Scope title: {{ yet.title }}
>       Parent title: {{ another.title }}
>       Parent parent title: {{ main.title }}
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> No hacky `$parent` calls. If a Controller’s position in the DOM/stack were to change, the position in sequential `$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent` may change! Accessing the scope lexically makes perfect sense.
>
> [— *Todd Moto*: Digging into Angular’s “Controller as” syntax (Nested scopes)](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/#nested-scopes)