# How to use the 'controller as' syntax with $ionic modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I am writing an app with AngularJS 1.5.3. I am using the $ionicModal service to show modals to my users.

I want to move my code into the 'controller as' syntax but I am not sure how to do that with the $ionicModal service.

Here is my controller code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myController', myController);

    myController.$inject = [
        '$scope',
        '$ionicModal',
        'myService'
    ];

    function myController($scope, $ionicModal, myService) {

        $scope.data = myService.data;

        $scope.openModal = openModal;

        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('./myPath/modal.html', function ($ionicModal) {
            $scope.modal = $ionicModal;
        }, {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        });

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            $scope.modal.remove();
        });

        function openModal() {
            $scope.modal.show();
        };

    }

})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to move my code into the 'controller as' syntax but I am not sure how to do that with the $ionicModal service.

#### Short answer

NO

#### Detailed answer

Ionic creates modal scope by calling:

```
var scope = options.scope && options.scope.$new() || $rootScope.$new(true);
```

When you use `ControllerAs` for your root controller suppose you have `vm` instance of the scope (a.e `vm = this;`).

**`vm` is not a `scope`!!!**.

`vm` is only object and there is no scope inheritance, it doesn't have `.$new()` method

So we cannot write `{scope: vm}` but only `{scope: $scope}`

---

For sure you can play with Ionic code but it can lead to unexpected behavior

Answer (score 1):

Ionic modal options [may include parent scope as `scope` option](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/controller/ionicModal/#initialize),

> scope The scope to be a child of. Default: creates a child of $rootScope.

It is similar to [UI Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33164461/3731501) in this regard. So it should use `$scope` any way to set up proper scope hierarchy. There's nothing wrong with using `$scope` together with controllerAs syntax when necessary.

Considering that the controller has `$ctrl` controllerAs identifier, it should be something like:

```
function myController($scope, $ionicModal, myService) {
    var self = this; // === $scope.$ctrl
    self.data = myService.data;
    self.openModal = openModal;

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('./myPath/modal.html', function (modal) {
        self.modal = modal;
    }, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    });

    self.$onDestroy = function () {
        self.modal.remove();
    });

    function openModal() {
        self.modal.show();
    };
}
```